# RPC/DCOM Implementation

Tags: com, wmi, rpc, wmi-query, dcom

I want to develop a program to perform [WMI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-start-page) queries on a remote windows server/machines. The client can be running on Windows or Linux. The porgamming language of choice is Golang.

From my research so far, this can be done using Microsoft DCOM with NTLM auth to secure the transactions.
DCOM is built on top of RPC specs. A similair project that has done this is the [Aiowmi Library](https://github.com/cesbit/aiowmi). It establish connection with the remote machine that runs on the same network, sends WMI queries and perform them on the remote mahcine and returns the resuslt.

The library isn't well-documented and I lack the enough knowledge of network/distributed protocols to understand it without guidence

- My question is, how to move past the point of just reading/studying the [RPC](https://publications.opengroup.org/c706), the [RPCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-rpce/290c38b1-92fe-4229-91e6-4fc376610c15), and the [DCOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dcom/4a893f3d-bd29-48cd-9f43-d9777a4415b0) docs, to start implementing the required components for my program?
- There're dozens of components that can be used/implemented?
- how can I identify the ones that I need?
- Are there other topics I should review that is required to move forward with this project?